# is there a way to show a players score on a sign?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

is there a way for a specific players score from a scoreboard to be shown on a specific sign. for example in a game of ice hockey a scoreboard shows the score of the 2 two teams (this would be the signs on minecraft)

this is a screen shot of what the physical and virtual scoreboard look like.[image]

This is 1.8.3 minecraft for the pc!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with `setblock`. [This](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/redstone-discussion-and/351959-1-8-raw-json-text-examples-for-tellraw-title-books) is a great tutorial that I use a lot.

Basically, you can set the NBT data of a sign when you setblock it. Just do

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:wall_sign 0 replace {
    Text1:"{
        selector:\"@p[team=Team1]\"
    }",
    Text2:"{
        score:{
            name:\"@p[team=Team1]\",
            objective:\"points\"
        }
    }"
}
```

This will create a sign with the closest player from team Team1's name on the first line and their score in `points` on the second line. You can also color the lines, choose different players, etc. There is really a *lot* you can do with it.

Comment: thank you so much! i have been researching this for 3 days and nothing came up!

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that's possible on Vanilla Minecraft. However, you can write your own bukkit plugin, the tutorials on that's available all over the net.